# empty css file style my page in dreamweaver?

Tags: css, dreamweaver, wampserver

I had a header.css file for styling my header part of php, I deleted it and recreated the same file in the same place, then I linked it to my page, but when I debug my page via wampserver it is styled like the deleted style sheet!!
This is very strange I deleted all www directory and puted my new files again but that doesn't change!
For example I don't set my header div color in stylesheet but it is gray in the browser!
I haven't had this problem in live view it is just in WampServer. I deleted my browser history but the problem still exists!

Comment: Try clearing your cooking and reload it again

Comment: @Benjamin *cookies >.<

Comment: @PatsyIssa thats a typo trying to edit it back but since my time got expired I dont.

Comment: On a side note dreamweaver is absolute garbage for anything related to development, there are plenty of alternatives out there that are better (sublime text, atom, brackets...).

Comment: @PatsyIssa So who worried about dreamweaver

Comment: I am advising the op not to use it, it has nothing to do with the problem that's why i started my sentence with "on a side note".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I cleared my browser cooking and it solved my problem.

Comment: You can post the comment in answer blocks.